# VLookup in VBA userforms - string lookup value

Tags: vba, vlookup, userform

I have got an issue with a vlookup function in VBA userform. Using below code it only seems to work when it is numeric value, however I have got values like G9000 which when selected throw error back I have tried to cast it as string but mismatch error comes up. There is multiple threads on the subject online, however it doesn't seem to work in my case. I am using this to update value in one of the boxes using change event. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub cb_safety_observers_id_Change()

With Me
.tb_safety_observersName = Application.VLookup(Val(Me.cb_safety_observers_id), employeeSheet.Range("emp_list"), 2, 0)
End With
```

End Sub

[image].

Comment: Returning an error because the vlookup failed to find what it is looking for? Do you have trailing or leading whitespace in your range?

Comment: @Warcupine I have investigated this first and the same data is in the form and in the table I am populating from. Also there is no white spaces at the beginning or at the end of the value.

Comment: Use more variables. Make a variable for each thing so you can inspect them. Set the texbox at the very end, after you have stepped through the code at each line and inspected the state of the variables. You know, debug it. We can't debug your code for you.